# What's the best PHP library to develop GUI programme?

Tags: php, user-interface

php-gtk and JeCat ?

Is there a better choice?

Further more,what's the current most pupular way to develop GUI programmes with PHP?

What's the procedures and related software utilities?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that it be PHP? Because PHP is not exactly a good GUI programming language.

Comment: I can only programme in PHP for the time being:)

Comment: I would bet it's HTML with his brother CSS and sister JS :)

Answer (score 4):

php-gtk will give you the least hassle, however any choice comes with a bit of a learning curve. I'm now using php-gtk + the [Roadsend PHP compiler](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler) to compile PHP desktop applications into native 32 bit ELF executables.

I should also add, it was not my choice to use PHP for such a task, I would much rather write desktop apps using C or Python. In the above case, I inherited something that was *prototyped* using PHP, which never got re-written. It was faster to just get it to compile than it was anything else.

I don't want to kick off a flame fest on the merits of using PHP as a prototyping tool .. in essence, *any* dynamically typed language could be used as such, depending on what had to be prototyped.

I would, however, encourage you to keep going on your self-study, once you grasp the concepts of the gtk bits that PHP exposes, consider looking into Python if you want to create applications that will be released to the wild.

Comment: Will the Roadsend PHP compiler work for 64 bit platforms?

Comment: Can you talk a little about the procedure of developing GUI software with php-gtk and Roadsend?

Comment: @Mask - There's no real special procedure, per say. You just write your script as you normally would, then follow the tutorials on roadsend to get it to compile. I'd first just experiment with running them under native PHP .. then play with roadsend or PHC (see phpcompiler.org)

Answer (score 1):

[TitaniumApp](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/). It allows you to design your GUI using Javascript, CSS and HTML5 (Runs a reasonably up to date version of webkit) and allows your code logic to be in PHP, Python, Ruby or Javascript. Produces executables for Linux, OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [PHP-Qt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-qt/)

Comment: http://www.php-qt.org is for sale :(
I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows-only is enough for you I've used [miniPHP](http://www.exvision.net/miniphp/) successfully for a real-world project.